# There are two classes with same name. How to select an element in one of them using css/xpath in Webdriver.IO?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriver-io

I use Webdriver.io and want to select an element inside class "text-fields-container" (its is a password field). Both classes have same name. How can I select second class which has type="password".

```html
<form>
 <div class="text-fields-container">
  <div>
   <input type="text" class="text-field" placeholder="Email" required stype="margin-bottom: 1.125rem;">
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="password" class="text-field" placeholder="Password" required stype="margin-bottom: 5px;">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

To select the second class which has **type="password"** you can use either of following *Locator Strategies* :

- `cssSelector` :

  ```
  "input.text-field[type='password']"
  ```
- `cssSelector` (granular) :

  ```
  "input.text-field[type='password'][placeholder='Password']"
  ```
- `xpath`

  ```
  "//input[@class='text-field' and @type='password']"
  ```
- `xpath` (granular) :

  ```
  "//input[@class='text-field' and @type='password' and @placeholder='Password']"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='text-field'])[2]"));`